# Why is a dynamical system not a dynamic system?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ho.history-overview

This is a research question in the history of math, I suppose.

As a non-native english speaker I became used to mathematical expressions like 'dynamical' and 'tangential'. When using them in daily conversation as substitutes for 'dynamic' and 'tangent' I got frowned upon by native english speakers who claimed to have never heard of these words before.

Some references suggest

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dynamical

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tangential

that indeed they **can** almost mean the same as 'dynamic' and 'tangent' but for some reason nobody seems to use these words that way.

So whereas in English:

A dynamic person-a dynamical system

the adjective is different

it is in French

une personne dynamique- un système dynamique

and in German

Eine dynamische Person - ein dynamisches System

the adjective is the same.

I am wondering when (and maybe also why) these expressions started deviating in English.

Comment: "Dynamic system" is also used, although less common.

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-04868-9_2

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Dynamic-Systems-David-Luenberger/dp/0471025941

Comment: "Tangential" is a perfectly fine word and I'm surprised people suggested otherwise. For example, I would say "your remarks are tangential to the main issue" to suggest that someone was getting off track. Saying "tangent" in that sentence sounds weird to me. As for dynamics, my inclination is that "dynamical" puts the emphasis on "being in the subject of dynamics" while "dynamic" means its usual thing (changing a lot, etc.). There is a similar phenomenon in "arithmetic" vs "arithmetical".

Comment: While we're discussing the language, why "a vector space" and "a moduli space" ('vector' and 'moduli' as nouns) in English but "un espace vectoriel" and "un espace modulaire" ('vectoriel' and 'modulaire' as adjectives) in French?

Comment: By the way, since, as you mention, this is in some way a history question, if it gets closed here then you might try [HSM](http://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @LSpice: I guess this has to do with the fact that adjectives in English come before the noun, and thus such a position for the related noun makes it a determinative, so makes it semantically equivalent to an adjective.

Comment: @LSpice: English is perfectly happy with noun-noun compounds separated by space. "Dinner table", "meal ticket", "brick wall", "chicken soup". In grammar this is called [attributive nouns](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attributive_noun). English is just much happier using nouns as adjectives compared to French which demands the preposition (compare, "mur en briques", "table à dinner" etc.)

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN, right, I certainly agree that [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366856/why-is-a-dynamical-system-not-a-dynamic-system#comment926786_366856)'s how it's functioning; I'm just curious why, for example, English doesn't call them "vectorial spaces" and "modular spaces", or why French doesn't call them … whatever the analogue would be in French ("un vecteur espace"?).

Comment: @LSpice: I've definitely used "un vecteur espace" at least once when lecturing in French.... The (Swiss) students found it hilarious, along with all my Americanisms.

Comment: @WillieWong, re https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366856/why-is-a-dynamical-system-not-a-dynamic-system#comment926793_366856 —nothing like (trying) to speak another language to make one more understanding of others' imperfect practice in one's own language.  :-)

Comment: The difference between "historic" and "historical" is somewhat analogous. But not exactly. Both "historic event" and "historical event" are used but have different meanings. As for "dynamic system" and "dynamical system", I can't think of when I would use the former.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the two entries from Anthony Lo Bello's *Origins of Mathematical Words* (John Hopkins, 2013) which is very informative, entertaining, and perhaps curmudgeonly.  In his parlance, following the lexicographer Samuel Johnson, a "low word" is one with an "irregular combination" of roots that has "little or no etymological legitimacy."

**dynamical**  The Greek noun *[dunamis]* means *power*.  The corresponding Greek adjective is *[dunamikos]*, *pertaining to power*.  The correct English adjective is therefore *dynamic*.  To superimpose the vestige *-al* of the Latin adjectival ending *-alis* upon the stem of a Greek adjective is often the product of ignorance and produces a low word.  In other cases, the addition of the Latin suffix to the Greek adjective is due to the fact that a different meaning is intended from that of the Greek adjective; thus, *dynamic* was an established word, so one spoke of *dynamical systems* rather than *dynamic systems* to avoid confusion.

**tangential**  See the entry **tangent**.  The Latin adjectival suffix *-alis* was added to the stem of the participle *tangens*, *tangentis*, which was already an adjective but felt to be a noun, *the tangent*.

Answer (score 12):

Thing is, they do **not** mean the same thing. At least, not in theory.

**Dynamic** the *adjective* means "exhibiting continual change".

**Dynamics** the *noun* means "the study of forces and their relation to motion".

**Dynamical** the *adjective* means "relating to the study of dynamics."

A "dynamic" system is a system exhibiting continual change. A "dynamical" system is a system relating to the study of dynamics. (Since OP is Chinese, this is also why DS is 動力系統 and not 不定系統.)

Similarly,

**Tangent** the *adjective* means the geometric notion of touching but not intersecting.

**Tangent** the *noun* refers first to the geometric construct of the line tangent to a shape, and then also to the idea of "objects that can be split off without making a turn", whence the idea of "going on a tangent" when you derail the discussion with something related but not directly relevant. (You won't be going on a tangent if you change the topic or the direction of discussion abruptly.)

**Tangential** the *adjective* refers to the quality of "tangent". Hence you make a "tangential remark" while you "go on a tangent". Hence you look for "tangent lines" while compute "tangential forces". (The force itself is not tangent, but it is directly along the line that is tangent to the object.)

---

This, of course, gets muddled by the fact that English is perfectly happy with [attributive nouns](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366856/why-is-a-dynamical-system-not-a-dynamic-system#comment926787_366856). English being remarkably loosey goosey about grammar for a Western language, understanding in theory why things are the way they are is probably much less useful than accepting their use as a convention. (After all, what is language but a convention to enable communication?)

---

Homework exercise: discuss **transverse** versus **transversal**

Comment: Lo Bello (see my answer for bibliographic details) on transversal: Though *transversus* is already an adjective, Albertus Magnus (1193-1280) superimposed the adjectival suffix *-alis* upon the stem to create the adjective *transversalis*, from which the English adjective was derived. Albert wrote the first original commentary on Euclid's *Elements of Geometry* in the Latin language,

Comment: Actually, there's a (somewhat famous) comment of Whitehead on this: "Transversal" is a noun; the adjective is "transverse.": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_(mathematics)

Comment: My "exercise" was actually posed with @PeterDalakov's solution in mind.

Comment: Surely the adverb should then be "transversely", but that same wiki page insists on "transversally".

Answer (score 5):

Early uses of "dynamical" go back to the 19th century at least:

- [On a dynamical theory
  of gratings](https://www.jstor.org/stable/92655%20), Lord Rayleigh (1907)
- [On the dynamical
  theory of gases](https://doi.org/10.1098/rstl.1867.0004), J.C. Maxwell (1865)

Thermo-dynamical as an adjective was also common, see for example [W. Gibbs's Thermodynamical Model](https://doi.org/10.1038/061414a0) (1900).

Answer (score 5):

This is a subtle question of scientific jargon. Indeed, in everyday language, "dynamic" is preferred, and "dynamical" at most is seen as an awkward synonym. My feeling is that "dynamic system" would be the everyday language way of referring to a system that was actually changing in time, moving. Whereas a "dynamical system" in physics, mathematics and at least to some extent beyond is a system that by its nature is capable of exhibiting change in time, i.e., being dynamic; moreover, we make a statement about the reason for that capability, i.e., there is some description of what causes its specific dynamism. One distinguishes between a merely kinematical description and a dynamical description - a kinematical description merely addresses *how* something moves, whereas a dynamical description addresses *why* something moves (say, some variational principle).

Indeed, with respect to the latter sentence, there's a clear contrast: A "dynamic description" would be a description that itself changes in time; a "dynamical description" is one that explains the change in time of some other object that is being referred to.

Comment: Why are you using "kinematical" instead of "kinematic"?  I don't think that in the term "kinematic description", the label "kinematic" is about the description itself having an attribute from within kinematics.  If a physical process were explained using thermodynamics, I think the term "thermodynamic explanation" would sound like a reasonable label.  At the same time, the terms "electric/electrical" have a usage distinction but there is no term "magnetical" to go along with "magnetic".

Comment: @KConrad - Indeed, I don't see a clear distinction between "kinematical" and "kinematic". I probably just used "kinematical" here for symmetry with "dynamical". I didn't think much about it. "Kinematic description" sounds fine. And "magnetical" is hilarious, I have to start using that as a joke. You illustrate perfectly how language isn't something one can press into simple rules. It's phantastomatic.

Comment: You mean phantastomatical... :)